# Wrong output of RegionPlot

Tags: plotting, regions, inequalities

I think Mathematica goes wrong if asked to plot this very simple region:

```
Region2 = ImplicitRegion[x < -1 && y < -1/x, {{x, -3, 0}, {y, 0, 1}}]
```

by means of the command

```
RegionPlot[Region2, PlotRange -> {{-3, 0}, {0, 1}}]
```

The output is

[image]

while I expected the region *below* the curve.

Do you know why this happens and how it can be solved?

Comment: I get the correct plot: http://i.stack.imgur.com/DOovW.png  (V11.3.0, MacOS)

Comment: I get the region you expect on 11.3

Comment: Thanks ì for the comments. So, do you think it is a bug of the version that I'm currently using (10.3, Win 8.1) ?!

Comment: MMA v11.0.1 also gives a wrong result. Try `RegionPlot[x < -1 && y < -1/x, {x, -3, 0}, {y, 0, 1}]`

Comment: So the idea is to bypass the command ImplicitRegion?

Comment: Works as expected with version `10.4.1 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (April 11, 2016)`

Comment: I get OP's (wrong) region `10.0 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (December 4, 2014)`.

Comment: But when not using `ImplicitRegion`, it's fine.

Comment: Works correctly with 11.2.0.0 for Mac OS X.